# Windows program for automatic image compression

Tags: windows, file-compression

I have a folder that has a lot of images within side it and new images are often put inside there.

However, the images are of high quality and they do not need to be. Thus taking up a lot of extra space.

Is there a program that will constantly run and will compress any images that are placed within or are already in this folder?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How would the program distinguish between pictures already handled and new ones?

Comment: @JanDoggen If it had a list of the images or went by date modified